# How to find the appropriate weights to maximize the third coordinate while the first two are zeros

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let's assume, that $v_1, ..., v_n \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ and $ \lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n \in [0, 1] $

The $ v_1, ..., v_n $ vectors are given. I have to find the appropriate weights ($ \lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$) where:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i * v_i \approx \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
max
\end{pmatrix} $$

The first two coordinates should be around zero, and the third one have to be the as high as possible.

So I am looking for the appropriate weights, to reach the maximal value of the third coordinate if the first two are zeros.

I don't know about any algorithm using I could solve this. I am sure it exists, I just don't know the keywords to find it.

But if it is not that hard, then please give me hints about how could I solve it myself.

---

**Edit**

I've tried to solve it using the Simplex Method.

In this case $n=3$ and the values of the vectors are:

$$ v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -2\\ 2\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ -1\\ 2 \end{pmatrix} v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

In this example, the result is trivial ($ \lambda_1 = 0.5, \lambda_2 = 1, \lambda_3 = 0 $), but I would like to solve it using the simplex method, to understand it, and use it for $n > 3$ and/or different $v_i$ values.

The equations are:

$$ -2\lambda_1 + 1\lambda_2 + 1\lambda_3 \le 0 $$
$$ 2\lambda_1 - 1\lambda_2 - 1\lambda_3 \le 0 $$
$$ 2\lambda_1 - 1\lambda_2 + 1\lambda_3 \le 0 $$
$$ -2\lambda_1 + 1\lambda_2 - 1\lambda_3 \le 0 $$
$$ 1\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 + 1\lambda_3 = p $$
$$ \lambda_{1, 2, 3} \le 1 $$

After rearranging equations:
$$ -2\lambda_1 + 1\lambda_2 + 1\lambda_3 + 0S_1 + 0S_2 + 0S_3 + 1S_4+0S5+0S6+0S7+0p= 0 $$
$$ +2\lambda_1 - 1\lambda_2 - 1\lambda_3 + 0S_1 + 0S_2 + 0S_3 + 0S_4+1S5+0S6+0S7+0p= 0 $$
$$ 2\lambda_1 - 1\lambda_2 + 1\lambda_3 + 0S_1 + 0S_2 + 0S_3+0S_4+0S5+1S6+0S7 + 0p= 0 $$
$$ -2\lambda_1 + 1\lambda_2 - 1\lambda_3 + 0S_1 + 0S_2 + 0S_3+0S_4+0S5+0S6+1S7 + 0p= 0 $$
$$ -1\lambda_1 - 2\lambda_2 - 1\lambda_3 + 0S_1 + 0S_2 + 0S_3+0S_4+0S5+0S6+0S7 + 1p = 0 $$
$$ 1\lambda_1 + 0\lambda_2 + 0\lambda_3 + 1S_1 + 0S_2 + 0S_3+0S_4+0S5+0S6+0S7 + 0p = 1 $$
$$ 0\lambda_1 + 1\lambda_2 + 0\lambda_3 + 0S_1 + 1S_2 + 0S_3 +0S_4+0S5+0S6+0S7+ 0p = 1 $$
$$ 0\lambda_1 + 0\lambda_2 + 1\lambda_3 + 0S_1 + 0S_2 + 1S_3+0S_4+0S5+0S6+0S7 + 0p = 1 $$

From these equations, the simplex table is:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_3 & S_1 & S_2 & S_3 & p &  \\ \hline
-2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
2 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
-1 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

I select the column, where the last row has the most negative value. That is the $\lambda_2$ row. Then I have to select the row, where the value in the last column divided by the value in the selected column is the smallest. But the value of the last column at the first two rows are always zero, and I don't know which one should I choose.

Comment: This is a typical linear programming problem. Look up the simplex algorithm to solve it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

Comment: I tried to use simplex algorithm, but my case is special, because $v_i$ can be negative, and the sum of the first two coordinates of the vectors (multiplied by the weights) have to be exactly zero.

Comment: the lowest non-zero ratio, or the lowest absolute value ratio?

Comment: Try making a harder example. This $n=3$ example proved too easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_i= \begin{pmatrix}
v_{i1}\\ 
v_{i2}\\ 
v_{i3}
\end{pmatrix} $

Then your LP will take the form:

Maximise $v_{13}\lambda_1+ v_{23}\lambda_2+ ... +v_{n3}\lambda_n $

Such that

$v_{11}\lambda_1+ v_{21}\lambda_2+ ... +v_{n1}\lambda_n =0$

$v_{12}\lambda_1+ v_{22}\lambda_2+ ... +v_{n2}\lambda_n =0$

$\lambda_1\le1$

$\lambda_2\le1$

$...$

$\lambda_n\le1$

Your variables are the $\lambda_i$ and they will be constrained automatically to be greater than or equal to zero. The signs of the $v_{ik}$ do not make any difference to the success of this approach.

Rewrite the equalities as pairs of inequalities:

Maximise $v_{13}\lambda_1+ v_{23}\lambda_2+ ... +v_{n3}\lambda_n $

Such that

$v_{11}\lambda_1+ v_{21}\lambda_2+ ... +v_{n1}\lambda_n \le 0$

$-v_{11}\lambda_1- v_{21}\lambda_2- ... -v_{n1}\lambda_n \le 0$

$v_{12}\lambda_1+ v_{22}\lambda_2+ ... +v_{n2}\lambda_n \le 0$

$-v_{12}\lambda_1- v_{22}\lambda_2- ... -v_{n2}\lambda_n \le 0$

$\lambda_1\le1$

$\lambda_2\le1$

$...$

$\lambda_n\le1$

You're going to have use a two-stage simplex algorithm because of equalities... thought you might have been able to get away without doing so, but no...

I have looked again at this and I can see how you can avoid the two-stage simplex algorithm.

In your example case you have the equations:

$$ -2\lambda_1 + 1\lambda_2 + 1\lambda_3 = 0 $$
$$ 2\lambda_1 - 1\lambda_2 + 1\lambda_3 = 0 $$
$$ 1\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 + 1\lambda_3 = p $$
$$ \lambda_1 \le 1 $$
$$ \lambda_2 \le 1 $$
$$ \lambda_3 \le 1 $$

Set $\lambda_3=2\lambda_1-\lambda_2$ and substitute throughout to yield:

$$ 2\lambda_1 - 1\lambda_2 + (2\lambda_1-\lambda_2) = 0 \Rightarrow 4\lambda_1-2\lambda_2=0 \Rightarrow \lambda_2=2\lambda_1$$
$$ 1\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 + (2\lambda_1-\lambda_2) = p \Rightarrow 3\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = p$$
$$ \lambda_1 \le 1 $$
$$ \lambda_2 \le 1 $$
$$ 2\lambda_1-\lambda_2 \le 1 $$

We are left with

$$\lambda_2=2\lambda_1$$
$$3\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = p$$
$$ \lambda_1 \le 1 $$
$$ \lambda_2 \le 1 $$
$$ 2\lambda_1-\lambda_2 \le 1 $$

Set $\lambda_2=2\lambda_1$ and substitute throughout to yield:

$$3\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_1 = p \Rightarrow 5 \lambda_1=p$$
$$ \lambda_1 \le 1 $$
$$2\lambda_1 \le 1 \Rightarrow \lambda \le \frac 12$$
$$2\lambda_1-2\lambda_2 \le 1 \Rightarrow 0 \le 1$$

We are left with

$$p = 5\lambda_1$$
$$ \lambda_1 \le \frac 12$$

You don't even need to use simplex algorithm!

To maximise $p$ you just need to maximise $\lambda_1$, so set $\lambda=\frac 12$.

Then $\lambda_2=2\lambda_1=1$

$\lambda_3=2(\frac 12)-1=0$

$p=5(\frac 12)=2.5$

Comment: I've tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVzjXpwW2xI  I my case there is no $S_1$ and $S_2$ and the last column in the first two rows are zeros. In each step I have to choose the row, where the value in the last column divided by the value at the selected column is te lowest. But $ 0 / x = 0 / y $, so I don't know which row should I choose. Only the $ \lambda_1 < 1 $ rows have a value of 1 at the last column, but they will never be selected, because $1/x$ is always larger than $0/y$

Comment: I've updated the question